# VehicleUpdatingVariableListener is removed from 7.2 optaplanner which was there in version 6.0

Tags: optaplanner

```
public class VehicleUpdatingVariableListener implements PlanningVariableListener<Customer> {}
```

Above class has been removed in 7.2 final.
In my implementation of Optaplanner I have written piece code inside **updateVehicle** method which is inside above class.

```
protected void updateVehicle(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Customer sourceCustomer) {}
```

The added code is used when the vehicle gets updated in Customer, I used to update the counterpart vehicle also.
**counterpart** : Added a extra shadow variable.

So,How could I do it in version 7.2  ?

**Edit 1**

```
protected void updateVehicle(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Customer sourceCustomer) {
        Standstill previousStandstill = sourceCustomer.getPreviousStandstill();
        Vehicle vehicle = previousStandstill == null ? null : previousStandstill.getVehicle();
        Customer shadowCustomer = sourceCustomer;
        while (shadowCustomer != null && shadowCustomer.getVehicle() != vehicle) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCustomer, "vehicle");
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCustomer.getCounterpartCustomer(),"vehicle");
            shadowCustomer.setVehicle(vehicle);
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCustomer, "vehicle");
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCustomer.getCounterpartCustomer(),"vehicle");
            shadowCustomer = shadowCustomer.getNextCustomer();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was renamed to ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/domain/timewindowed/solver/ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.java)

Comment: @GeofferyDeSmet Thanks for quick response. ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener is for updating arrivalTime , but I want to update the vehicle Shadow variable. I have edited question with code snippet